# Confused with cache line size

Tags: c++, linux, memory, cpu

I'm learning CPU optimization and I write some code to test **false sharing** and **cache line size**. I have a test struct like this:

```
struct A {
  std::atomic<int> a;
  char padding[PADDING_SIZE];
  std::atomic<int> b;
};
```

When I increase `PADDING_SIZE` from 0 --> 60, I find out `PADDING_SIZE < 9`  cause a **higher cache miss rate**. `PADDING_SIZE >= 9` cause a **lower cache miss rate**.

I don't think 9 is the correct answer, 60 is. Because `sizeof(int) + 60` is cache line size(64byte)

### Total Code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include <atomic>

struct A {
  std::atomic<int> a;
  char padding[PADDING_SIZE];
  std::atomic<int> b;
};
int loop_count = 1000000000;

void f1(struct A* ptr) {
  for (int i = 0; i < loop_count; ++i) {
    ptr->a = i;
  }
}

void f2(struct A* ptr) {
  for (int i = 0; i < loop_count; ++i) {
    ptr->b = i;
  }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  auto start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
  A* a = new A();
  std::cout << sizeof(A) << std::endl;
  std::thread t1 = std::thread(f1, a);
  std::thread t2 = std::thread(f2, a);
  t1.join();
  t2.join();
  auto end = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
  std::cout << "Cost: " << (std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(end - start)).count() << " microiseconds" << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

### Compile

```
g++ main.cc -g -std=c++11 -g -lpthread -DPADDING_SIZE=8
g++ main.cc -g -std=c++11 -g -lpthread -DPADDING_SIZE=9
```

### Test Result

> Perf result generate by: `perf stat -d ./a.out`

[With Padding == 8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mtvsh.png)

[With Padding >= 9](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VV4Ou.png) [Why >= 9? Because all test results is simliar]

### Enviroment

1. Ubuntu 20.04
2. gcc9.4.0
3. No NUMA
4. `/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cache/index0/coherency_line_size` is **64**.

### Question

1. Is the code wrong?
2. Why padding size >= 9 make a different? Just because two atomic variable split to different **16bytes** memory? (Instead of **64byte**)
3. How to get the **actual cache line size**?

Thanks.

Comment: You seem to assume that your `A` starts at the beginning of a cache line. Do you have any reason to assume that?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/hardware_destructive_interference_size

Comment: Thank you for reply.I did make this wrong assumption. The cppreference you linked is helpful. I will take more test on it.

Comment: `alignas(64) std::atomic<int> a;` inside the struct will align it by 64.  Or check the address of the struct in a debugger, like check `&a->a` and `&a->b` to see if they're in different cache lines, to see if your existing code was doing that.